# How to declare derivatives of a multivariable function as real in order to get Re and Im part of the expression?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, function-construction, symbolic, complex

`Re` and `Im` work properly, with appropriate assumptions, in the example like this

```
Assuming[g[_, _] ∈ Reals, Simplify[Im[3*I*g[r, r2] + 45]]]
```

On the other hand, if the derivative of the function is also present, similar approach does not work

```
Assuming[(r | g[_, _] | D[g[_, _], _]) ∈ Reals, Simplify[Im[3*I*D[g[r, r2], r] + 45]]]
```

i.e. does not give back `3*D[g[r, r2], r]`

More dramatically,

```
Assuming[(r | g[_, _] | f[_]) ∈ Reals, Simplify[Im[3*I*(D[g[r, r2]*f[r], r]) + 45]]]
```

gives `3 Re[g[r,r2] (f^′)[r]+f[r] (g^(1,0))[r,r2]]`.

In real problem, I have the function of four variables and mixed partial derivatives, so it would be great if there is some generic way to prescribe all of function's derivatives as Real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of the derivatives:

```
Assuming[(r | g[_, _] | Derivative[1, 0][g][_, _]) ∈ Reals, 
   Simplify[Im[3*I*D[g[r, r2], r] + 45]]]
```

[image]

```
Assuming[(r | g[_, _] | f[_] | Derivative[1, 0][g][_, _] | Derivative[1][f][_]) ∈ Reals, 
   Simplify[Im[3*I*(D[g[r, r2]*f[r], r]) + 45]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Great, it works! Form `Derivative[_, _][g][_, _]` allows for generalizing to arbitrary number of derivatives.